# Why do model learn better on the same data copied few times?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, supervised-learning

I've faced something I can't understand. I am working with ANN, model is pretty simple, only few dense layers. As an input I have 8 columns with standarised values, problem is supervised learning, regression. For now I have X_train of shape (37160, 8). I've tried training model, but it didn't perform well: [image: plot]

Later on I was working with my data and I messed up something with indexes while merging dataframes. It created copies of my data on my original file. At first I didn't notice that now my X_train has shape of (185800‬, 8) and I started fitting model. It was exactly the same model as above, as well as data, just the same rows copied few times. I realised something is wrong due to higher time for each epoch, however I didn't stop it and this is the result: 
[image: plot 2]

I am newcomer to data science, just exploring basics and maybe it is a dumb question and the answer is silly, but can someone explain me what and why happened? Why the second model is learning better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you (or the fit method) possibly did random splits into training and testing, this is a beautiful example of train/validation leakage.

If e.g. each observation is replicated six times, then most of them will both appear in the training data as well as in the validation data. As such, the validation data is not anymore independent and is more like a copy of the training data (whose performance gets better and better by overfitting).

Comment: Now it is pretty obvious for me, thanks for your answer ;)

Comment: It was a good question!